# Process 'clamd' "not monitored"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, monit, clamav

the output of monit summary says clamav is not monitored.
The configuration says:

```
check process clamd with pidfile /var/run/clamav/clamd.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start"
  stop  program = "/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon stop"
  if failed unixsocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

I can confirm the pid file exsists, that the start and stop commands work when testing via

```
monit start clamd
```

Yet 'monit summary gives the following:

```
Process 'clamd'                     Not monitored
```

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you actually have a PID in the PID file you specify at: `/var/run/clamav/clamd.pid`.

That's all `monit` is using to track this process, so make sure that you're using the right file and path, and that there's something people populated in the file upon subsequent restarts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your clamd configuration: /etc/clamav/clamd.conf and check "PidFile" if you dont see that you have to add it:

```
PidFile /var/run/clamav/clamd.pid
```

and restart clamav:

```
service clamav-daemon restart
```

or you can configure mmonit service without pid file:

```
check process <PROCESS NAME>
        matching <PROCESS NAME>
        start program = "/etc/init.d/<PROCESS NAME> start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/<PROCESS NAME> stop"
```